# libraries not found error/ library path in makefile

Tags: c, linux

I am compiling my code with

```
gcc  -o ./sample/createUsageXMLd ./obj/createUsageXML.o  -L../../../third_party/lib/openssl-fips/2.0/LSBGCC64 -L../../../third_party/lib/curl/7.45.0/LSBGCC64  -lssl -lcrypto
```

But I get error
/

```
usr/bin/ld: warning: libssl.so.1.0.0, needed by ../../../third_party/lib/curl/7.45.0/LSBGCC64/libcurl.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libcrypto.so.1.0.0, needed by ../../../third_party/lib/curl/7.45.0/LSBGCC64/libcurl.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
../../../third_party/lib/curl/7.45.0/LSBGCC64/libcurl.so: undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_set_srp_username'
../../../third_party/lib/curl/7.45.0/LSBGCC64/libcurl.so: undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_set_srp_password'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have the following in my 
libraries third party folder

```
$ cd third_party/lib/openssl-fips/2.0/LSBGCC64/
$ ls
libcrypto.a  libcrypto.so  libcrypto.so.1.0.0  libssl.a  libssl.so  libssl.so.1.0.0
```

Comment: Do you try to use `-rpath` or `-rpath-link` option as mentionned ?

Comment: I don't see the libraries you want to link, the compiler option -L adds new directories to the beginning of the library search path, but you must tell the compiler which libraries in those directories you want to link with the -lNAME option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried installing curl with yum install. I checked the version of installed curl.It was 7.29.0. My compilation was successful. Later I degraded the version of curl from 7.45.0 to 7.29.0 in third_party folder. Now it compiles fine

Answer (score 1):

You also need to provide the name of the library that you wish to link,

`gcc file.c -o file -L/path/to/libs -llibname`

In your case, try providing -lssl after including the path to your libraries (which you've done using -L). Note that the prefix "lib" and suffix ".so" are not required.

Comment: yes I am providing the -lssl -lcrypto, updated in original message